# Complex numbers inequality with absoulte value

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I've got a inequality to prove.

$z_1,z_2,...,z_n \in \mathbb{C}$

$ | \prod_{i=1}^n(1+z_i) -1 | \le \prod_{i=1}^n (1+|z_i|) -1 \le \exp(\sum_{i=1}^n |z_i|) -1$

So I started from :

$e^x \ge 1+x$

$\exp(\sum_{i=1}^n |z_i|) -1 = \exp(|z_1|)\exp(|z_2|)...\exp(|z_n|)-1 \ge \prod_{i=i}^n (1+|z_i|) -1$

That was easy part. What to do about second inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second inequality comes from the triangle inequality. Indeed, develop the product $\prod_{i=1}^n (1+z_i)$. You get

$$
 \prod_{i=1}^n (1+z_i) = \sum_{I \subset \{1, \ldots, n\}} \prod_{i \in I} z_i$$

So applying the triangle inequality, you get

$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\prod_{i=1}^n (1+z_i) - 1 &=& \sum_{I \subset \{1, \ldots, n\},\, I \ne \emptyset} \prod_{i \in I} z_i \\
&\le& \sum_{I \subset \{1, \ldots, n\},\, I \ne \emptyset} \prod_{i \in I} |z_i| \\
&=& \prod_{i=1}^n (1+|z_i|) - 1
\end{eqnarray*}$$

The last equality comes from the same computation as before (applied to $|z_1|, \ldots |z_n|$).